# Getting a shared pointer to a derived class when base class inherits from enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, boost

I have a class B which inherits from A which in turn derives from `enabled_shared_from_this`. Now, I want to get a shared pointer to B from an instance of B. `shared_from_this` will return `shared_ptr<A>`, not `shared_ptr<B>`. Should I use `boost::static_pointer_cast` here? Or is there a better way?

Comment: `static_pointer_cast` sounds all right. After all, you do *know* when you are in `B` that your object is indeed a `B`. No dynamic check of any sort is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a valid approach as the type is known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case more preferable to use [boost::dynamic_pointer_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/pointer_cast.html);

```
boost::shared_ptr<B> b = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(shared_from_this());
```